# compileSdkVersion is not specified error in React Native Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I get the build error when I try to build an Android app in my React Native project.

When I run `react-native run-android`, it says:

```
> Configure project :react-native-os
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-os'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.
```

In Android Studio, I can see that it says the same thing:
`Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified.`

So I edited build.gradle(Module: app) file in Android Studio, but the problem persists and the error message doesn't change.

```
android {
//    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

I tried solutions in other threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487859/cause-compilesdkversion-is-not-specified) but nothing worked. Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same issue solved by :

1- run `npm i @react-native-firebase/app` in terminal

2- follow [these steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) to add firebase to the android platform.

Comment: why do we need firebase library if we are not using firebase?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have in android/app/build.gradle:

```
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

(This error happened to me after I accidentally changed configurations.compile to configurations.implementation)

Comment: Thanks Man : I Also did the same mistake +1

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest and effective solution if this is happening with react native**
Move to node_module/@react-native-firebase/
for all modules example- app, firestore etc.
Go to their android folder and open build.gradle
you will see,

```
project.ext {
  set('react-native', [
    versions: [
      android : [
        minSdk    : 'same your project version root folder/android/app/build.gradle',
        targetSdk : 'same your project version root folder/android/app/build.gradle',
        compileSdk: 'same your project version root folder/android/app/build.gradle',           
        buildTools: 'same your project version root folder/android/app/build.gradle'
      ],

      firebase: [
        bom: firebaseBomVersion,
      ],
    ],
  ])
}
```

Hope this made it work. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I don't understand, what is the solution you are proposing? move to node_modules and what?

Comment: @verunar Change above mentioned versions to same as your app's versions

Answer (score 1):

My issue was caused by `node` command not found by gradle.

```bash
# fixed by linking the node path to the /usr/bin/node
# node is binary was located in $HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/bin/node
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/bin/node
```

When I run the above command the issue above disappeared.

If you are getting "Operation not permitted" error, please use the following:

```
# you might need to create the /usr/local/bin directory if it doesn't exist
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: I'm getting "Operation not permitted on this answer" even when I use sudo

Comment: @UcheNkadi I have updated the answer to help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *node_module>@react-native-firebase>messaging>android>build.gradle*

Find code which defines min and target sdk and define the sdk and build version same as you have in your main project *build.gradle* file.

Then run command *cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..*

Also make sure you had defined default firebase config in your app level *build.gradle*
Make sure you have this import on top your *build.gradle* :
*apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"*
and an default config as :
`defaultConfig { applicationId "..." minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion versionCode 00 versionName "... multiDexEnabled true }`

Answer (score 1):

i just solved my issue by install @react-native-firebase/app, i was using firebase messaging but firebase/app was not installed

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **Android Supported Library**.

If you are **27+ Supported Library** you should use **compileSdkVersion 27** and **targetSdkVersion 27**

Comment: Hmm...I downgraded and restarted to build again, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am too later to answer but the possible reason is if your build.gradle version is above 7 than you also may be getting the error of maven, Plugin with id ‘maven’ not found. If you try to follow the steps and solve that error that sdk compile error vanishes.

https://lifesaver.codes/answer/plugin-with-id-maven-not-found-12774

This worked in my case

Comment: I am in a similar situation. Sadly the link you posted does not work.

Comment: The link is not working